# Include Linux header file

Tags: c++, linux

How could I include a linux header file? I read from the web that the header file is in `/usr/include`. However, the header file I need is not in that directory; it is in `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32.../include/linux/`.

I tried to include the file using the full path. However, the file itself includes other header files as well. Hence, the compiler couldn't find the other header files when I compile.

How could I include the header file in my program and compile the program?

Comment: Which specific header file is it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files

Answer (score 10):

If you are on Ubuntu, install `libcpufreq-dev`. This will give you the `cpufreq.h` header at `/usr/include/cpufreq.h`, which you can include from your code with `#include <cpufreq.h>`.

Comment: Get the header installed is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

By default, gcc searches the following directories for header files:

```
/usr/local/include/
/usr/include/
```

and the following directories for libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/lib/
```

The compiler options -I and -L add new directories to the beginning of the include path and library search path respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You may add to your `gcc` command line `-I` (for "includes") options which specify other directories to search for include files (besides or actually even instead of the normal ones like `/usr/include`, though it's so long since I last needed the "instead of" that I don't recall how that's done == `man gcc` should tell you in 5 minutes if you need to find out;-).